# How to check if ID already exist - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

When user selects an item, I store the `id` of the item in a `hidden input` on the panel. Now when user selects the same item, I want to check if the `id` already exists on the panel and if it does, I will change the value of quantity from 1 to 2.

How can I achieve this?

PS: With the code below, when the user selects an already existing item on the panel, it append the item again and I keep having duplicates.

```
function findID(sol)
{
    var products = JSON.parse(sol.dataset.sol);

    if(sol.checked == true)  {
        $('.panel').append(
            '<div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; "> '+
            '<input type="hidden"  value='+products.id+' data-id="'+products.id+'"   name="food_id[]" />'+
            '<table style="width:100%;" class="table" id="tables">'+

            '<tbody id="item_list">'+
            '<tr>'+
            '<td  class="name" >'+products.name+'</td>'+
            '<td><input size="50" type="text"  value="1" class="form-control quantity" id="qty" placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/></td>'+
            '</tr>'+
            '</tbody>'+
            '</table>'+
            '</div>'

        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest storing the ids in an array on the panel in a data field, like `$('.panel').data('selectedIds', idArray);`  Then you can get that array off the panel and do an `indexOf()` on it to see if the id was previously selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to scan the DOM for the elements you have already added and if it exists find the `.quantity` element and increase the value. Other wise add it as you already do

```js
function findID(sol) {
  var products = JSON.parse(sol.dataset.sol),
    existing;

  if (sol.checked == true) {
    existing = $('.panel input[data-id="' + ad.id + '"]');

    if (existing.length) {
      // already added, just increase the count
      existing.closest('.container').find('.quantity').val(function(i, value) {
        return parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
      })
    } else {
      // not yet added. Add it now
      $('.panel').append(
        '<div class="container" style=" font-size:14px; "> ' +
        '<input type="hidden"  value=' + ad.id + ' data-id="' + ad.id + '"   name="food_id[]" />' +
        '<table style="width:100%;" class="table">' +

        '<tbody id="item_list">' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<td  class="name" >' + ad.name + '</td>' +
        '<td><input size="50" type="text"  value="1" class="form-control quantity" placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]"  required/></td>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>'

      )
    }


  }
```

---

I have also removed all the `id` attributes from the elements you add because they have to be unique.

Comment: @LearnLaravel yes sorry, i changed a variable name without updating the rest. Now should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ids on the panel as a data element and check them there.

```
var selectedIds = $('.panel').data('selectedIds') || [];

if (selectedIds.indexOf(newSelectedId) > -1) {
    //id already selected
    //do whatever logic
} else {
    //id not already selected
    selectedIds.push(newSelectedId);
    $('.panel').data('selectedIds', selectedIds);
    //do your other logic
}
```